# $\liminf A_n\subset \limsup A_n$ - is this proof convincing?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is this proof convincing? It looks right to me, but the change of variables I did makes me feel rather uneasy.

$1.$ If $a\in\liminf A_n$ then this is the same as $a\in\bigcup_{\delta\geq0}\bigcap_{k\geq\delta} A_k$, which is to say there is a $\delta>0$ such that if $k\geq \delta$ then $a\in A_k$ for very $k\geq \delta$.

$2.$ Given any $n\geq 0$, if $n< \delta$ then pick $k=\delta$, thus there is a $k\geq n$ such that $a\in A_k$; if $n\geq \delta$ pick $k=n$, thus there is a $k\geq n$ such that $a\in A_k$.

$3.$ We conclude: for any $n \geq 0$, there is $k\geq n$ such that $a\in A_k$. This is the same as $a\in\bigcap_{\delta\geq0}\bigcup_{k\geq\delta} A_k$.

I don't like 1., because $\liminf A_n$ is by definition $a\in\bigcup_{n\geq0}\bigcap_{k\geq n} A_k$. Changing the variable doesn't make a difference here, but should I write something else to justify it? It looks unsettling in my notes. Should I be more formal?

Comment: In step $1$, you should write $\delta\geq0$ instead of $\delta>0$ (even if it remains true...) and say that you pick such a $\delta$ (not only state that it exists). In step $2$, I would write "set" instead of "pick". Nevertheless, I don't see any problem with that change of variables.

Comment: I think your proof is fine: if $a$ is in $every$ set $A_k$ for all $k\ge \delta$ then surely $a$ is in $some$ set $A_k$ for all $k\ge 0.$

Comment: So your problem is that you are uneasy about using "$\delta$" instead of "$n$"? Of course, it doesn't matter what variable you use, provided you don't use the same variable to mean something else within the same context. $\delta$ is more tradionally used to vary over real numbers, not integers, but that is a just common practice, not a requirement. If it bothers you, use $m$ instead.